# AJAX table population with bootstrap buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

Have a base HTML I am appending NFL Teams and their scores to

```
 <table id="tablePreview" class="table table-hover table-sm">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Home Team</th>
  <th>Home Score</th>
  <th>Away Score</th>
  <th>Point Spread</th>
  <th>Button</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
```

I have simple Ajax call routine that will add 10 teams to the table.

```
function displaynflteams(){
var queryURL = "https://api.fantasydata.net/v3/nfl/scores/JSON/GameStatsByWeek/2018/8?key=ad398993c55d46449bde67a4095fef1b"
$.ajax({
url: queryURL,
method: 'GET'
})
.done(function(response) {
var results = response.data; 
if (results == ""){
alert("Seriously? There is nothing here");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
tr = $('<tr/>');
tr.append("<td scope=row>" + i + "</td>");
tr.append("<td>" + results[i].HomeTeam + "</td>");
tr.append("<td>" + results[i].HomeScore + "</td>");
tr.append("<td>" + results[i].AwayScore + "</td>");
tr.append("<td id=odds-1>" + results[i].PointSpread + "</td>");
tr.append("<td id=place-bets-1><button class=btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 id=pick-team-[" + i + "]>Select</button></td>";
$('table').append(tr);
}
});
}

displaynflteams();
```

For some reason the records are not showing up. I think it maybe the way I'm parsing my bootstrap attributes for the buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you are making a GET request to is `TootsieRollURL`. That it not a url, unless was it just changed for this post. Where are you trying to fetch the data from?

Also, if you did change out the url to hide it, can you verify the response data from browser devtools?

Comment: that was deliberately done as the issue was with the record creation

Comment: add URL for viewers to see the data